# monotone class theorem application, equality!

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, monotone-class-theorem

Ive been struggling trying to really learn what the monotone class theorem is about. I got the following problem:

Let $(\Omega,F)$ a measurable space and $\mathbb{A}\subset F$ an algebra. Let $\mu$ and $\upsilon$ two $\sigma-finite$ measures over $(\Omega,F)$ such that $\mu(A)=\upsilon(A)$ for all $A\in\mathbb{A}$. Show that $\mu(A)=\upsilon(A)$ for all $A\in \sigma(A)$.

**PROOF:**

Let $M=\{A\in \sigma(\mathbb{A}): \mu(A)=\upsilon(A)\}$

1. Let $(B_{j})_{j}\subset M$ s.t $B_{1}\subset B_{2}\subset...$

$\mu(\bigcup_{j}B_{j})=lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\mu(B_{j})$ by continuity over $\mu$.

$lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \mu(B_{j}))=lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \upsilon(B_{j})$ by hypothesis.

$lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \upsilon(B_{j})=\upsilon(\bigcup_{j}B_{j})$ by continuity of the measure.

Then $\bigcup_{j}B_{j}\in M$

2. Let $(B_{j})_{j}\subset M$ s.t $B_{1}\supset B_{2}\supset...$

$\mu(\bigcap_{j}B_{j})=lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\mu(B_{j})$ by continuity over $\mu$ and $\sigma-finite$.

$lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \mu(B_{j}))=lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \upsilon(B_{j})$ by hypothesis.

$lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \upsilon(B_{j})=\upsilon(\bigcap_{j}B_{j})$ by continuity of the measure and $\sigma-finite$.

Then , $\bigcap_{j}B_{j} \in M$

Finally, M is a monotone class, therefore $M\supset M(\mathbb{A})=\sigma(\mathbb{A})$

Is this proof correct?

Please, need all the possible help you can give cause this thing of monotone class stuff is making me really hard to keep forward with my study :c!

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: "In measure theory and probability, the monotone class theorem connects monotone classes and sigma-algebras. The theorem says that the smallest monotone class containing an algebra of sets G is precisely the smallest σ-algebra containing G."

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem

Comment: P. Halmos's *Measure Theory* is a good reference to have, to look into from time to time.

Comment: Thanks avs! But, is the proof right? o:

Comment: Cause, I can understand the concepts but Its really hard for me to know when im doing the things right haha :(